# Passing generic param of type "object" to WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamic

We have a requirement, that drives me into developing more generic WCF service.
Our server-side code receives dynamically constructed JSON from the UI.
Next, it de-serializes that JSON into an object (dynamic).
Is it possible to send such object to WCF?

Basically, is it possible to send an object of type "object" to WCF... ?

And then cast it to a strongly typed object within WCF?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't answer that, but is it not possible to send the JSON to the service and have it reconstruct the object as well?

Comment: To my knowledge, `dynamic` and Generics don't work in WCF. (Requires a strongly-typed `DataContract`)

Comment: Brad, it is partially true, in fact, "dynamic" type defined in WCF service becomes an "object" in client proxy, so technically it can be defined as "object" in WCF service, no difference.

Comment: Why not just send the Json to the wcf service?

Comment: @monstro That isn't  true. `dynamic` and `object` don't work that way.

Comment: @dai, what is not true and what way they don't work:-) ? try to declare "dynamic" parameter to WCF service method, and then generate a proxy in visual studio, you will see that parameter defined as "object"

Comment: @jfin4204, you absolutely right, that is another option, I'm thinking about... If the first approach is too problematic, I will go work this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF is strongly typed. It has to know how could it be serialized and deserialized. Unfortunately MEX is blind like a man who requires a guide dog. It discribes everything which are represented on Interface/Contract, so it will generate `object` for you :/, but it will not working.

If you need some kind of generic way to send anythintg from A to B, use manual serialization method, `xml` or `byte[]` or `Stream`. (but these are overkill for this issue and you could send JSON as well as @jfin3204 wrote)

Comment: Thank you, @sac, looks like you are right, I have done lots of experiments trying to make it work (WCF via interface, via dynamic, via object, via abstract, via parent class...) Nothing works as needed or not working at all. Looks like strongly typed object is the only way... And it makes sense since WCF needs to know into what to serialize the input.